# Center a TableLayout within a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Android newbie here.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/mMainTop"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mMainBottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    // some TextView

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mSubTable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
```

how can I center my `TableLayout` vertically with **reference** to the remaining space left in the parent `LinearLayout`?

I hope someone can understand what I mean.

Comment: have you tried "android:gravity="center"" on the parent LinearLayout?

Comment: Yes, I did tried. Maybe I didn't mention clearly. On top of the TableLayout there are a few TextView which I wish them to remain on the top of the screen. If I put gravity center, it will center everything.

Comment: @sk okay, I think you should set the height to match_parent then. Ie the height for the table view since the other text_views will be render led above it. And also set it's gravity to center so its contents are centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try and make `android:layout_gravity="center"` to `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` in your TableLayout

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mSubTable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following attributes to LinearLayout

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="cneter_vertically"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set height the LinearLayout `match_parent`